# Is the TYPO3 Site Kickstarter broken in TYPO3 v7.6

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

Is the TYPO3 Site Kickstarter broken in TYPO3 v7.6?

I get an error about incompatible versions of VHS when I try to install it (3.1.0 vs 4.1.0).

Comment: Do you use composer?
Could you please write what you did before you got the error?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the extension "site" (https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/site)?

The extension *site* version 1.7.0 for TYPO3 7 has the following dependencies:

- *flux*
- *vhs*
- *fluidcontent*
- *fluidpages*
- *builder*

Whereas *builder* has an explicit dependency on an older *vhs* version 2.2.0-3.99.99. By default, a newer *vhs* 4.2.0 would be installed for TYPO3 7.6. So there is a discrepancy with the versions.

However, it should probably not be a problem. Let's assume *site* actually runs with *vhs* 4.2.0 inspite of the older dependency declaration.

What you can do as a workaround:

Install *vhs* first, and then install *site* and continue in spite of the warning.

If you want to use this suite of extensions, it is probably not a bad idea, to upgrade to TYPO3 8 soon.